# How do I avoid recomputing variables in this python class?

Tags: python, numpy

In the snippet below, how do I avoid computing the following numpy variables `mask`, `zbar`, `te` , `ro` and `rvol` in the procedures `Get_mask`, `Get_K_Shell_Te` etc? These variables are large arrays and I have to define at least six more procedures that reuse them. It looks like what I am doing is not a good idea and is slow.

```
import numpy as np
# this computes various quantities related to the shell in a object oriented way
class Shell_Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
         self.data = data

    def Get_mask(self):
          zbar=self.data['z2a1']
          y=self.data['y']*1000 
          mask= np.logical_and(zbar >= 16  ,zbar<= 19  )
          return self.mask

    def Get_Shell_Te(self):
          self.mask =self.Get_mask()
          te   =self.data['te'][self.mask]
          ro   =self.data['ro'][self.mask]
          rvol =self.data['rvol'][self.mask]
          self.Shell_Te=np.sum(te*ro/rvol)/(np.sum(ro/rvol))
          print "Shell Temperature= %0.3f eV"  % (self.Shell_Te)
          return  self.Shell_Te

     def Get_Shell_ro(self):
          mask =self.Get_mask()
          te   =self.data['te'][mask]
          ro   =self.data['ro'][mask]
          rvol =self.data['rvol'][mask]
          radk =self.data['radk'][mask]
          self.Shell_ro=np.sum(radk*ro/rvol)/np.sum(radk/rvol)
          return self.Shell_ro
```

Comment: How about calculating them in the `__init__` method and store them in the object?

Comment: will simply defining `zbar` , `ro` and `rvol` in __init__ make them accessible in `Get_Shell_ro` ?

Comment: You need to assign the to `self.ro` and access them using the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`zbar` depends on `self.data`. If you update `self.data`, you likely have to re-compute it.

If you can make your data immutable, you can compute these values once, e.g. in the constructor.

If you want to avoid calculating the mask data until it's actually required, you can cache the value, like so:

```
class Shell_Data(...):

   def __init__(self,...):
     self.cached_mask = None
     ...

   # @property makes an access to self.mask
   # to actually return the result of a call to self.mask()
   @property
   def mask(self):
     if self.cached_mask is None:  # Not yet calculated.
       self.cached_mask = self.computeMask()
     return self.cached_mask

   def computeMask(self):
     zbar = ...
     ...
     return np.logical_and(...)

   def someComputation(self):
     # The first access to self.mask will compute it.
     te = self.data['te'][self.mask]
     # The second access will just reuse the same result. 
     ro = self.data['ro'][self.mask]
     ...
```

If you have to mutate `self.data`, you can cache the computed data, and re-calculate it only when `self.data` changes. E.g. if you had a `setData()` method for that, you could recalculate the mask in it, or just set `self.cached_mask` to `None`.

(Also, read about instance variables again.

Every method receives the parameter named `self`, the instance of the object for which it is called. You can access all its instance variables as `self.`*something*, exactly the way you access instance variables (and methods) when an object is not called `self`. If you set an instance variable in one method, you can just access it an another (e.g. `self.mask`), no need to return it. If you return something from a method, likely it's not worth storing as an instance variable, like `self.mask`.)